# CakePHP Locale not updating

Tags: cakephp, locale

I have an issue with locale cakephp translations. I had to update some texts, which are not showing up on my page. Previously added texts are being displayed correctly. I tried deleting all cache folders (models, views, persistent). I have also tried setting debug level to 3. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we both have the same issue. What I've gathered is that calling translations from a specific domain seems to brake the translation according to the core's language setting.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer in my case here:

http://www.quindev.com/blog/2010/01/cakephp-i18n-problem-of-updating-po-files-with-a-text-editor/

It turns out I had edited the translations with PoEditor, which created .mo files in addition to the .po files. It turns out CakePHP prefers the .mo files and ignores the .po files when present.

Just removing the .mo files from the translation folder fixed the issue.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete files from

```
/tmp/persistant/
/tmp/models/
/tmp/views/
```

And in web browser press CTRL+F5 to refresh page

Comment: "I tried deleting all cache folders (models, views, persistent)." And to be more accurate its: /tmp/cache/persistent/

Comment: Check your views __('input') and locale files (is it the same variable name). Check Locale file tags (msgid "Hey, bonjour"
msgstr "hello")

Comment: It is exactly the same.